# Finding Euclidean distance from a m*n dimensional matrix to a point

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

I am working on a clustering problem. There's a situation where I have 3 cluster centers as below, and I want to calculate euclidean distance from these 3 cluster centers from another m*n dimensional matrix. It would be very helpful if anyone can guide me through this.

```
kmeans.cluster_centers_
Out[99]: 
array([[-2.23020213,  0.35654288],
       [ 7.69370352,  1.72991757],
       [ 0.92519202, -0.29218753]])
matrix
Out[100]: 
array([[ 0.11650485,  0.11650485,  0.11650485,  0.11650485,  0.11650485,
         0.11650485],
       [ 0.11650485,  0.18446602,  0.18446602,  0.2815534 ,  0.37864078,
         0.37864078],
       [ 0.21359223,  0.21359223,  0.21359223,  0.21359223,  0.29708738,
         0.35533981],
       ..., 
       [ 0.2640625 ,  0.2734375 ,  0.30546875,  0.31953125,  0.31953125,
         0.31953125],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,
         1.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,
         0.5       ]])
```

I want to do it in Python. I have used sklearn for my clustering.

Comment: add you code / attempts

Comment: I haven't really attempted anything. A little confused, actually how to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Euclidean distance is from a point to point. (2-d to 2-d, or 3-d to 3-d, n-d to n-d as Anony-Mousse said). Here your first array contains 2-d points (clusters), but second array contains 6-d values. So how would you calculate distance between them

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance is defined on vectors of a fixed length d.

I.e.it is a function R^d x R^d -> R

So whatever you are trying to do - it is not the usual Euclidean distance. You seem to have k=3 cluster centers with d=2 coordinates, but your matrix has an incompatible shape that cannot be interpreted in an obvious way as 2 d vectors.